# create json array with php

Tags: php, arrays, json, codeigniter-3

I find it difficult to create JSON data.
I was wanna make out JSON like the picture below

[image]

but I'm having trouble.
I am only able to make like the picture below

[image]

The following code I created. please help me, I am really very confused

```
foreach ($q->result() as $row){
  $djson[] = array(
    'id' => $row->id_custome,
    'name' => $row->nama_custome
    );
}
return $djson;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the key/index

```
        foreach ($q->result() as $key=>$row){
          $djson[ ( $key + 1 ) ] = array(
              'id' => $row->id_custome,
              'name' => $row->nama_custome
          );
        }
        return $djson;
```

Note: `$key + 1` because you want to start the json from `1`.

Comment: thank you very much, really i'm so happy :) now i can, thanks again

Comment: Great! Im happy to help.